# How to merge two images into a single Jpeg

Tags: c#, image

I need to be able to take multiple images and overlay a smaller one on top of a larger one and save the result as a single image.
How would I go about accomplishing this in C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Load the first image using [new Bitmap(filename)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f(v=VS.100).aspx)
2. Load the second image the same way.
3. Get a Graphics object by calling [Graphics.FromImage(bitmap1)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage(v=VS.100).aspx)
4. Call [graphics.DrawImage(bitmap2...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yws82c40(v=VS.100).aspx) to put the second image on the first
5. Call [bitmap1.Save(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah(v=VS.100).aspx) to save the new image to a file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the environment that you're working and what you want to do with the resulting image.

If it's within a Winforms or console application then GDI+ would be one way to do it.
Examples of how to do such manipulations can be found at [Bob Powell's GDI+ FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20140714181132/http://bobpowell.net/gdiplus_faq.aspx).

If it's within a WPF, Silverlight or XNA then there are better alternatives available.