# How to split Image and merge splitted images in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-4.0

In my application i want to split a image and merge splitted images in different order,After that re-arrange that images.How can i implement this in c#?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge two images into a single Jpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687820/how-to-merge-two-images-into-a-single-jpeg)

Comment: The `System.Drawing` namespace and `System.Drawing.Bitmap` class contain everything you need.

Comment: You could split the image with [Bitmap.Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find lot's of tutorials on this and similar processes on the web. See for instance:

- [How to crop image in CSharp](http://www.webkeet.com/webtutorials/tabid/78/id/73/how-to-crop-image-in-aspnet-csharp.aspx)
- [Combining Images with C#](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/combining-images-with-csharp)
- [Merging images in .Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12789/Merging-Images-in-NET)
- [Combine several images to form a single image using C#](http://www.niteshluharuka.com/2012/08/combine-several-images-to-form-a-single-image-using-c/)